# What is the best way to cancel a blocking request in node-redis?

Tags: node.js, blocking, node-redis

I am experimenting with the [`node-redis`](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node-redis) library, and I'd like to use the blocking `blpop` command. My issue is that I'd like to wait an indeterminate amount of time, but potentially cancel waiting at any moment. Is there a way to cleanly cancel a call `blpop XYZ 0` without killing the redis connection? I don't seem to see any in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `CLIENT UNBLOCK` command (https://redis.io/commands/client-unblock/) from a different connection to force a different client off a blocking connection.

Before you issue your blocking command (i.e. `BLPOP XYZ 0`), make a `CLIENT ID` command to obtain the id of the connection you intend to block on. Then from a secondary "control" connection, issue the `CLIENT UNBLOCK` command:

`CLIENT UNBLOCK client-id [TIMEOUT | ERROR]`

Example from the documentation:

```
Connection A (blocking connection):
> CLIENT ID
2934
> BRPOP key1 key2 key3 0
(client is blocked)

... Now we want to add a new key ...

Connection B (control connection):
> CLIENT UNBLOCK 2934
1

Connection A (blocking connection):
... BRPOP reply with timeout ...
NULL
> BRPOP key1 key2 key3 key4 0
(client is blocked again)
```